# Bash: usage of `true`

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

In many scripts I've inherited from a former employee I keep seeing this pattern:

```
if (true $SOME_VAR)&>/dev/null; then
    ...
fi
```

or this one

```
(true $SOME_VAR)&>/dev/null || SOME_VAR="..."
```

The man page for `true` says it always returns true, hence I keep wondering, what is the point of these checks? In the first case the `then` part is always executed, in the second case the right hand part is never executed.

Comment: This is silly -- any shell having `&>` (which is an extension not specified in POSIX sh) will have much better alternatives (more idiomatic, less brittle -- and also less expensive in performance impact, as subshells are expensive). I wouldn't advise hanging onto this code going forward.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my job is to port this stuff to Python. I just want to be sure, I understand all the original intentions, hence the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `set -u` (a.k.a. `set -o nounset`) is in effect, `true $SOME_VAR` will fail when `$SOME_VAR` is not defined.  This is therefore a way to test whether the variable is defined.

Comment: Hm, I haven't seen the `set` command in any of the scripts in that codebase, yet. Thank you.

Comment: This could be the case, but it doesn't explain `(true $SOME_VAR)&>/dev/null || SOME_VAR="…"`, except possibly if the former employee didn't test their work. If `set -u` or `"${SOME_VAR?}"` is used, the bash error will abort any further part of the command, thus this will not set the variable.

Comment: @kojiro well, I've just tested it on Ubuntu and OS X and `(true $SOME_VAR)&>/dev/null || SOME_VAR="…"` does work as @jwodder says.

Comment: @kojiro The parentheses cause `true $SOME_VAR` to be executed in a subshell, so only the subshell will abort if the variable is unset.

Comment: Aha! It does work, but it's pretty messy. You have to cause an entire subshell to fail to capture that the variable is unset. In my tests I forgot the parens.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I'd suggest you replace this expression with something that doesn't require a subshell to test is a var is set. `SOME_VAR="${SOME_VAR:-default}"` comes to mind.

Comment: @kojiro yeah, I would've definitely used variable expansion to get this functionality, but I'm porting it to Python anyway.

Comment: @kojiro: given that this is Bash, then `"${SOME_VAR:=default}"`, use appropriately, will achieve that.  Agreed that the pattern in the question is ugly and brittle!

Comment: @TobySpeight: Good idea, though it should be  `${SOME_VAR=default}` (no `:`) to match the original behavior - but I suspect the original behavior not covering the defined-but-empty-value case is precisely what you meant by brittle.
Both forms are POSIX-compliant (not Bashisms).

Comment: Maybe `set -u` is in a `.bashrc` or similar. Yuk.

Answer (score 14):

To complement [jwodder's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744178/jwodder) and [Fred's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43049367/45375):

- In **Bash v4.2+**
  , the less obscure and more efficient **`-v` operator** can be used to **test if a variable is defined**<sup>[1]</sup> (note that *no* `$` must be used):
  `[[ -v SOME_VAR ]]`
- In **older Bash versions and in POSIX-compliant scripts**, use [Fred's parameter-expansion-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43049367/45375), which is also more efficient than the `(true ...)` approach.
- If the intent is to simply **provide a *default* value**, as in the `(true $SOME_VAR)&>/dev/null || SOME_VAR="..."` idiom, use the (POSIX-compliant) technique suggested by [kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro), also based on a [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):
  `SOME_VAR=${SOME_VAR-...} # keep $SOME_VAR value or default to '...'`
  [Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight) suggests another POSIX-compliant variant, `${SOME_VAR=...}`, which directly *updates* the variable with the default value, if it is undefined; however, it has the side effect of *expanding* to the (resulting) value - which may or may not be desired. A concise, but also slightly obscure way to suppress the expansion is to pass the expansion to the [colon (null) utility (`:`)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#colon), which expands, but otherwise ignores its arguments (compared to using `true` for the same purpose, it is perhaps slightly less confusing):
  `: ${SOME_VAR=...} # set $SOMEVAR to '...' only if not defined`
- Note that all parameter expansions shown/mentioned above have a ***variant* that places `:` before the operator**, which then **acts not only when the variable is *undefined*, but also when it is defined but *empty*** (contains the null string):
  `${SOME_VAR:+...}`, `${SOME_VAR:-...}`, `${SOME_VAR:=...}`
  Arguably, this variant behavior is the **generally more robust technique**, especially given that when `set -u` (`set -o nunset`) is *not* turned on, undefined variables expand to the null (empty) string.

To add to jwodder's explanation:

- The use of `(...)` around `true $SOME_VAR` to create a *subshell* is crucial for this somewhat obscure test for variable existence to work as intended.

  - Without a subshell, the *entire script* would abort.
  - **The need for a subshell makes the technique not just *obscure*, but also *inefficient*** (although that won't really be noticeable with occasional use).

    - Additionally, **if `set -u` (`set -o nounset`) happens *not* to be in effect, the technique treats *all* variables as defined.**
  - With the subshell, only the subshell aborts, which is reflected in its exit code to the current shell: `1`, if the subshell aborted (the variable doesn't exist), `0` otherwise.
    Therefore, the `(true ...)` command only evaluates to (conceptually) true if the variable exists.
  - `&>/dev/null` suppresses the error message from the subshell that is emitted if the variable doesn't exist.

    - As an aside: `true` never produces no output, so it is sufficient to use `(true $SOME_VAR)2>/dev/null` (suppress *stderr* only) - this change makes the technique POSIX-compliant (though still not advisable).
- It isn't just `set -u` (`set -o nounset`) statements *inside* a script that turn on aborting in case of access to an undefined variable - invoking `bash` explicitly with command-line option `-u` has the same effect.

---

<sup>[1] Since Bash **v4.3**, you can also test whether an *array* variable has an element with the specified *index*; e.g.:

`a=( one two ); [[ -v a[0] ]]` succeeds, because an array element with index `0` exists; works analogously with *associative* arrays.</sup>

Comment: Although the codebase is almost comment-free, it does have this line `supports shells with no [[ -v ... ]]`.

Answer (score 6):

The following is probably equivalent, and more straightforward :

```
if [ "${SOME_VAR+x}" ] then
    ...
fi
```

Or, in the assignment case :

```
[ "${SOME_VAR+x}" ] || SOME_VAR="..."
```

The `+` expansion operator expands to a null string if the variable is unset, and to `x` if it is assigned (assigned a null string still means assigned).  In this case, you could replace `x` by whatever you want (except a null string).

There is also a `${SOME_VAR:+x}` variant.  The difference is with null strings : `:+` expands to a null string if the variable is assigned a null string (while `+` expands to `x` if the value is assigned, even if it is a null string).

Comment: I guess, this is not as portable. The `true`-based method would even work on an archaic Bourne-shell. Having read the entire codebase, I think this was a portability-based decision. Anyway, my job is to rewrite it in Python.

Comment: @EliKorvigo: It is portable in a POSIX sense, which is probably all that matters these days. Note that the code in your question uses Bashisms.

Comment: For the assignment case, there's also the combined form `: ${SOME_VAR="..."}`. Here, `${SOME_VAR="..."}` is a variable expansion which sets `SOME_VAR` to `"..."` if it wasn't already set, and expands to `SOME_VAR`'s old or newly assigned value. `:` (`true` would work too) is then a command which simply ignores its arguments, merely used because `${...=...}` only exists in an expanding form.

Answer (score 3):

While not strictly the same,

```
if [ x"$SOME_VAR" = x ]; then
    ...
fi
```

tends to do what you want; that is the if is true if `$SOME_VAR` is undefined or (difference:) defined to be the zero-length string.

This code does not work if `SOME_VAR` is unset and `-u` is set. I believe the following bashism works though: `"${SOME_VAR-}" = ""`.

Comment: The `x` trick is only necessary with old, non-POSIX-compliant shells. `[ "$SOME_VAR" -eq "" ]` will work fine, although `[ -z "$SOME_VAR" ]` is possibly clearer.

Comment: @chepner: Ah yes more variants. I learned from reading ancient scripts. My environment didn't have -z but "" would have worked.

Comment: `[ "${SOME_VAR-}" = "" ]` is not in fact equivalent, as it conflates the empty and unset states. The original code tests only for unset, not for empty.

Comment: Moreover, `${SOME_VAR-}` is **absolutely not** a bashism; it's been defined by POSIX ever since the early-1990s release of issue 2, the first version to standardize the shell command language. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02 for the relevant text of a more recent version of said standard -- note that the example in the table uses `:-`, but surrounding text explains the behavior without the `:` and how it differs.